# How to return a specific item in Distinct using EqualityComparer in C#

Tags: c#, list, distinct, equals, iequalitycomparer

I have defined a `CustomListComparer` which compares `List<int> A` and  `List<int> B` and if `Union` of the two lists equals at least on of the lists, considers them equal.

```
var distinctLists = MyLists.Distinct(new CustomListComparer()).ToList();

public bool Equals(Frame other)
{
    var union = CustomList.Union(other.CustomList).ToList();
    return union.SequenceEqual(CustomList) ||
           union.SequenceEqual(other.CustomList);
}
```

For example, the below lists are equal:

```
ListA = {1,2,3}
ListB = {1,2,3,4}
```

And the below lists are NOT:

```
ListA = {1,5}
ListB = {1,2,3,4}
```

Now all this works fine. But here is my question: Which one of the Lists (A or B) gets into `distinctLists`? Do I have any say in that? Or is it all handled by compiler itself?

What I mean is say that the `EqualityComparer` considers both of the Lists equal. and adds one of them to `distinctLists`. Which one does it add? **I want the list with more items to be added.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distinct` always adds the first element which it see. So it depends on the order of the sequence which you passed in.

Source is fairly simple, which can be [found here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ab583c7d8e84d6d,references)

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) {
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
}
```

If you need to return list with more elements, you need to roll your own. Worth noting that `Distinct` is lazy, but the implementation you're asking for will need a eager implementation.

```
static class MyDistinctExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctMaxElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) where T : ICollection
    {
        Dictionary<T, List<T>> dictionary = new Dictionary<T, List<T>>(comparer);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            List<T> list;
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out list))
            {
                list = new List<T>();
                dictionary.Add(item, list);
            }
            list.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var list in dictionary.Values)
        {
            yield return list.Select(x => new { List = x, Count = x.Count })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                .First().List;
        }
    }
}
```

Updated the answer with naive implementation, not tested though.

Comment: Thanks Sriram for the source. Can you be more specific on how can implement that? I have trouble understanding this.

Comment: @Vahid Updated the answer with naive implementation, I've not tested it. If there is a problem drop me a comment.

Comment: I had trouble implementing it. `var distinctList = MyLists.DistinctMaxElements(new CustomListComparer()).ToList()`;

Comment: Post your code for `CustomListComparer`, and you said trouble implementing it, but never said what's the trouble? What happens? Compiler error? Post the [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Distinct` you can use `GroupBy` with `MaxBy` method::

```
var distinctLists = MyLists.GroupBy(x => x, new CustomListComparer())
                           .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.Count))
                           .ToList();
```

This will group lists using your comparer and select the list that has max item from each group.

`MaxBy` is quite useful in this situation, you can find it in [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library.

**Edit:** Using pure LINQ:

```
var distinctLists = MyLists.GroupBy(x => x, new CustomListComparer())
                           .Select(g => g.First(x => x.Count == g.Max(l => l.Count)))
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Selman, but I'm not using MoreLinq, can this be done using Linq?

Comment: @Vahid ofcourse, added that solution as well. but it won't be as effiecient as the first solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Selman. This is actually working very well. And this is the method I used in my code actually. To be consistent with the question I chose Sriram Sakthivel's answer which is also working well.